# How to sort the content of an HTML File according to the browser view?

Tags: html, css

We need to process a book with over 1500 pages written with QuarkXPress 2018 in a Python-Pipeline to use the data in a Triple Store. Unfortunately, QuarkXpress doesn’t provide a useful Export-Format for our purpose. The best it has is an HTML export.

This works well for the “normal” text in the document. But everything else like tables, pictures or special text-blocks are always at the end of the HTML document. The view in the browser is correct according to the original book because all the elements are positioned absolutely to each other.

[image]

The above picture shows on the left side of the browser-view and right the HTML-Document. The colors contain identical lines. As you see, the green, orange, yellow, blue and purple blocks get positioned within the red block (red block = normal text) to create the original view according to the book.

To solve the problem, we tried to import the HTML document in our Python-Pipeline and then import the same page as PDF-Document and to sort the HTML-Tags according to their position in the PDF-Document with simple string-matching. It works not bad but of course, doesn’t work for any pictures and has a too high rate of making mistakes. As the meta-Information (Titel, Subtitle, Table, etc.) of the tags is also important for us and available in the HTML document we also can’t only work with the PDF-Document.

As the browser displays the data in the correct order there must be a way to calculate that order. Does a tool exist which would sort the HTML tags in the order as they get displayed from the Browser?

You also find a simpler HTML and CSS file which shows the problem.

```css
.para-NoStyle-127 {
  font-family: 'Arial', 'ArialMT', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 140px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-font-kerning: Normal;
  font-kerning: Normal;
  -webkit-font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;
  font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "rlig" 0, "liga" 0, "clig" 0, "calt" 0, "locl" 0, "ccmp" 0, "mark" 0, "mkmk" 0;
  font-feature-settings: "rlig" 0, "liga" 0, "clig" 0, "calt" 0, "locl" 0, "ccmp" 0, "mark" 0, "mkmk" 0;
  color: #222021;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.QxpTextBox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: scale(0.05, 0.05);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.05, 0.05);
}

.QxpVertTextBox {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  line-height: 1;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  transform: scale(0.05, 0.05);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.05, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>
    237-276_DIV_CH
  </title>
  <meta content="width=369,user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
  <meta content="QuarkXPress 14.0.1" name="generator" />
  <meta content="text/html;CHARSET=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <link href="ProjectCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="../assets/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <style type="text/css">
    .panandzoom {
      -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
      -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    }
    
    a:link {
      color: blue;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    a:active {
      color: red
    }
    
    a:visited {
      color: purple
    }
    
    sub,
    sup {
      line-height: 0;
    }
    /* body style */
    
    body {
      background-color: white;
      color: #222021;
    }
    
    #box1 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 339.661px;
      top: 575.433px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 28px;
      height: 15px;
    }
    
    #box1_Props {
      padding: 2px;
      width: 24.346px;
      height: 10.74px;
    }
    
    #box2 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 27.85px;
      top: 43.243px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 312px;
      height: 532px;
    }
    
    #anchbox3 {
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 285px;
      height: 45px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #anchbox3_Props {
      background-color: #E1ECF5;
      width: 280.819px;
      height: 41.304px;
      padding: 2px;
    }
    
    #anchbox4 {
      position: absolute;
      width: 252px;
      height: 44px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #anchbox5 {
      position: absolute;
      width: 289px;
      height: 91px;
      display: block;
      page-break-inside: initial !important;
    }
    
    #box6 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 289px;
      height: 11px;
    }
    
    #box7 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 41px;
      height: 19px;
    }
    
    #box8 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 248px;
      height: 19px;
    }
    
    #box9 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 41px;
      height: 20px;
    }
    
    #box10 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 248px;
      height: 20px;
    }
    
    #box11 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 41px;
      height: 27px;
    }
    
    #box12 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 248px;
      height: 27px;
    }
    
    #box13 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 41px;
      height: 13px;
    }
    
    #box14 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 248px;
      height: 13px;
    }
    
    #anchbox24 {
      position: absolute;
      width: 289px;
      height: 123px;
      display: block;
      page-break-inside: initial !important;
    }
    
    #box25 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 289px;
      height: 11px;
    }
    
    #box26 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 40px;
      height: 36px;
    }
    
    #box27 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 248px;
      height: 36px;
    }
    
    #box28 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 40px;
      height: 27px;
    }
    
    #box29 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 248px;
      height: 27px;
    }
    
    #box30 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 40px;
      height: 19px;
    }
    
    #box31 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 248px;
      height: 19px;
    }
    
    #box32 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 40px;
      height: 27px;
    }
    
    #box33 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 248px;
      height: 27px;
    }
    
    #box43 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 342.496px;
      top: 104.882px;
      width: 91px;
      height: 44px;
    }
    
    #box44 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 27.85px;
      top: 19.843px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      width: 312px;
      height: 20px;
    }
    
    #box44_Props {
      border-width: 0.2px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #222021;
      width: 308.411px;
      height: 16.341px;
      padding: 1.5px;
    }
    
    a.nostyle {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
    }
    
    .page {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 369px;
      height: 595px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="margin:0%;">
  <div class="page" id="section1">
    <div id="box1">
      <div id="box1_Props">
        <!-- bg -->
      </div>
      <div class="QxpTextBox" style="left:2px;top:2px;">
        <span class="char-Normal-Local-22" style="top:-18.73px;">173</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
      <div class="QxpTextBox">
        <div style="position:absolute;left:42.52px;top:0.00px;width:6194px;height:220px;background-color:#005BAA;">
          <!-- 
        Rule -->
        </div>
        <span class="char-Titulo_0_principal-Local-80" style="left:42.52px;top:10.90px;">Herzinsuffizienz (HII)</span>
        <span class="char-Titulo_0_principal-Local-80" style="left:5716.00px;top:10.90px;">[I50.9]</span>
        <div style="position:absolute;left:0.00px;top:191.19px;width:6236px;height:20px;background-color:#005BAA;z-index:-1;">
          <!-- 
        Rule -->
        </div>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:623.62px;top:951.69px;">-</span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:793.70px;top:951.69px;">Inzidenz in der Schweiz: 20’000 neue Fälle/Jahr</span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:623.62px;top:1112.68px;">-</span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:793.70px;top:1112.68px;">Mortalität der akuten HI: &gt; 50 %/12 Mt. (ohne Therapie der Grundkrankheit)</span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:453.54px;top:1273.68px;">•</span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:623.62px;top:1273.68px;">Der wichtigste Faktor, welcher zur Verschlimmerung der HI beiträgt ist die neurohumorale </span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:623.62px;top:1434.68px;">Aktivierung (d.h. Aktivierung des Sympathikus und des RAAS)!</span>

        <div style="position:absolute;left:0.00px;top:2710.48px;width:6236px;height:200px;background-color:#646364;">
          <!-- 
        Rule -->
        </div>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="top:2750.93px;">Klas:</span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-176" style="left:510.24px;top:2750.93px;">«Zeitliche» Klassifizierung</span>

        <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:453.54px;top:2968.62px;">1.</span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:623.62px;top:2968.62px;">Akute Herzinsuffizienz</span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:453.54px;top:3129.62px;">2.</span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:623.62px;top:3129.62px;">Akute Dekompensation einer Herzinsuffizienz</span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:453.54px;top:3290.62px;">3.</span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:623.62px;top:3290.62px;">Chronische Herzinsuffizienz</span>

        <span class="para-NoStyle-115" style="left:453.54px;top:7378.32px;">Tabelle: Klassifikation der Herzinsuffizienz nach der NYHA.</span>

        <div style="position:absolute;left:283.46px;top:7635.24px;width:5953px;height:180px;background-color:#646364;">
          <!-- 
        Rule -->
        </div>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-176" style="left:510.24px;top:7655.68px;">ACC/AHA Klassifikation</span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-327" style="left:2099.73px;top:7661.29px;font-size:91px;"> </span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-195" style="left:2125.01px;top:7672.61px;">[</span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-195" style="left:2158.35px;top:7672.61px;">ACC/AHA Guidelines. JACC 2001;38:2101</span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-195" style="left:4432.96px;top:7672.61px;">]</span>


        <span class="para-NoStyle-115" style="left:453.54px;top:10337.87px;">Tabelle: ACC/AHA Klassifikation der HI.</span>
      </div>
      <div style="position:absolute;left:23.68px;top:81.61px;">
        <div id="anchbox3">
          <div id="anchbox3_Props">
            <!-- bg -->
          </div>
          <div class="QxpTextBox" style="left:2px;top:2px;">
            <span class="para-NoStyle-9" style="top:-5.43px;">Für die PRAXIS</span>
            <div style="position:absolute;left:0.00px;top:137.76px;width:1027px;height:20px;background-color:#005BAA;z-index:-1;">
              <!-- 
                Rule -->
            </div>
            <span class="para-NoStyle-18" style="top:183.91px;">Es ist essentiell, die URSACHE des Syndroms «Herzinsuffizienz» zu suchen!</span>
            <span class="para-NoStyle-18" style="top:344.91px;">Die häufigsten Ursachen der HI in den westlichen Ländern sind:</span>
            <span class="para-NoStyle-18" style="top:505.91px;">•</span>
            <span class="para-NoStyle-18" style="left:170.08px;top:505.91px;">Koronare Herzkrankheit (KHK) →  i.d.R. systolische Dysfunktion </span>
            <span class="para-NoStyle-18" style="top:666.91px;">•</span>
            <span class="para-NoStyle-18" style="left:170.08px;top:666.91px;">Arterielle Hypertonie (AHT) →  i.d.R. diastolische Dysfunktion</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="position:absolute;left:31.82px;top:174.41px;">
        <div id="anchbox4">
          <img alt="77.png" class="qxpASDImage" height="45" src="assets/77.png" width="253" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="position:absolute;left:22.68px;top:391.66px;">
        <div id="anchbox24">
          <table class="table1_1">
            <colgroup>
              <col style="width:14.07%;" />
              <col style="width:85.93%;" />
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="td1_1" colspan="2">
                  <div id="box25">
                    <div class="QxpTextBox" style="left:2px;top:2px;">
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-36" style="top:-7.62px;">ACC/AHA Klassifikation der Herzinsuffizienz</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="td1_11">
                  <div id="box26">
                    <div class="QxpTextBox" style="left:2px;top:2px;">
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-36" style="top:-16.61px;">Grad A</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="td1_12">
                  <div id="box27">
                    <div class="QxpTextBox" style="left:2px;top:2px;">
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="top:-16.61px;">•</span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:49.01px;top:-16.61px;">   </span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:170.08px;top:-16.61px;">Patienten mit hohem Risiko, eine HI zu entwickeln (z.B. art. Hypertonie, </span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:170.08px;top:144.39px;">KHK, Diabetes mellitus, Alkoholabusus, Kokainabusus u.a.).</span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="top:305.39px;">•</span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:49.01px;top:305.39px;">   </span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:170.08px;top:305.39px;">Keine strukturellen oder funktionellen Myokard-, Perikard- oder </span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:170.08px;top:466.39px;">Klappenabnormitäten. Keine Symptome.</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="td1_6">
                  <div id="box28">
                    <div class="QxpTextBox" style="left:2px;top:2px;">
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-36" style="top:-16.61px;">Grad B</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="td1_7">
                  <div id="box29">
                    <div class="QxpTextBox" style="left:2px;top:2px;">
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="top:-16.61px;">•</span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:49.01px;top:-16.61px;">   </span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:170.08px;top:-16.61px;">Patienten mit struktureller Herzkrankheit, welche aber keine Symptome </span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:170.08px;top:144.39px;">oder Befunde einer HI aufweisen (z.B. linksventrikuläre Hypertrophie oder </span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:170.08px;top:305.39px;">Dilatation, Status nach Myokardinfarkt u.a.).</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="td1_2">
                  <div id="box30">
                    <div class="QxpTextBox" style="left:2px;top:2px;">
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-36" style="top:-16.61px;">Grad C</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="td1_3">
                  <div id="box31">
                    <div class="QxpTextBox" style="left:2px;top:2px;">
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="top:-16.61px;">•</span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:49.01px;top:-16.61px;">   </span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:170.08px;top:-16.61px;">Patienten mit aktuellen oder vorgängigen HI-Symptomen, welche einer </span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:170.08px;top:144.39px;">strukturellen Herzkrankheit zuzuordnen sind.</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="td1_6">
                  <div id="box32">
                    <div class="QxpTextBox" style="left:2px;top:2px;">
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-36" style="top:-16.61px;">Grad D</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="td1_7">
                  <div id="box33">
                    <div class="QxpTextBox" style="left:2px;top:2px;">
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="top:-16.61px;">•</span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:49.01px;top:-16.61px;">   </span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:170.08px;top:-16.61px;">Patienten mit fortgeschrittener struktureller Herzkrankheit und schweren </span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:4659.85px;top:-16.61px;">         </span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:170.08px;top:144.39px;">HI-Symptomen, trotz max. medikamentöser Therapie (inkl. Spezialisten-ein-</span>
                      <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="left:170.08px;top:305.39px;">griffen).</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>

              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box43">
      <img alt="NORME_onglet.png" class="qxpASDImage" height="44" src="assets/NORME_onglet.png" width="91" />
    </div>
    <div id="box44">
      <div id="box44_Props">
        <!-- bg -->
      </div>
      <div class="QxpTextBox" style="left:1.7px;top:1.7px;">
        <span class="para-NoStyle-127" style="top:-2.40px;">Der Update 2018 des Kapitels HERZINSUFFIZIENZ kann wie folgt eingesehen werden:</span>
        <span class="char-Normal-Local-374" style="top:168.89px;"></span>
        <span class="para-NoStyle-36" style="left:131.80px;top:164.61px;"> http://www.investimed.ch/HERZINSUFFIZIENZ_2018.pdf</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="../assets/PressRunWidgets.js" type="text/javascript">
    /* Script */
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't know if such code is out there, but I doubt it.  HTML is source code.  It is run through an interpreter to produce an in-memory representation of the page called the DOM.  Once the DOM is built, the interpreting program then renders the DOM to the screen.  This interpreter and renderer is, of course, usually a web browser.  You don't need the second part, the rendering.  You just need the first part, the building of the DOM.  Or you need something that tries to hack its way through the HTML and understand it without actually interpreting the HTML as code....

Comment: To do anything but a full interpretation of the page will be a process very specific to the content you have.  if each of your pages is formatted the same way, there's at least some hope of you doing this, as shown by the success you've already had.  But to expect a module to be out there that will do this without interpreting the HTML as code is quite a stretch because it would have to be general in nature, not specific to a particular page layout.  There's really only one general solution, and that's to interpret the HTML as code...

Comment: The way to do that is to script the execution of a browser so that it creates the DOM, and then you can us the DOM to do your translation to whatever format or formats you're interested in producing.  The alternative is, I think, what you're already doing...just keep looking at the raw HTML and extract patterns that you can leverage in your code to extract what you need without actually interpreting the page.

Comment: It's possible that someone has put a clean front end on the execution of a browser to come up with a DOM.  This is one possible site seems to possibly do that:  https://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/.  You can google for others.  I googled for "html to dom".